# Rails - How do I write jQuery to handle the JSON Data that server respond?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

In Rails, if I add `remote: true` to a link, then it will request using Ajax, but when server send `JSON` back, in client-side, what I should write for handling this data?

Could anyone help me?  Thanks.

**Update**

In Rails, like this code, just add `remote: true`, it will send request using Ajax:

```
<%=  form_tag(add_link_to_a_shared_list_url, :method => "post", :remote => true) do %>
    <%= select_tag "shared_list_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@shared_lists, "id", "title") %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:link_id, link.id) %>
    <%= submit_tag "submit", :class => "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

I want to write some jQuery code to catch JSON and put it into DOM.

Exactly speaking, the code that handle Ajax request we don't need to write because it was be handled by Rails, but we need to write the code that handle JSON Data respond from server .

Comment: Can you add in a sample response that you are expecting your serverto send back?

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

A simple example would be:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "url",
            data: {
                   input : yourInput
            },
            success: function(output){
                   // do something with the output
            }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish between UJS and JSON API.

UJS：The server returns Javascript, the client receives direct execution(Do not need remote: true, but have format.json).

```
$("new_reply_form").on "submit", (event) ->
  $.ajax(
    url: $(this).prop("action")
    dataType: "json"
).done (data) ->
  # local logic
  return
```

JSON API：The server returns data, the client receives local processing before performing.

First: remote: true

```
<%= form_for(@reply, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Second: format.js

```
   def create                                                                          
     @entry = Entry.new(params[:entry])                                                

     respond_to do |format|                                                            
       if @entry.save                                                                  
         format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'Entry was successfully created.' } 
         format.js                                                                     
       else                                                                            
         format.html { render action: "new" }                                          
         format.js                                                                     
       end                                                                             
     end                                                                               
   end
```

Third: action_name.js.erb

```
<% if @reply.errors.empty? %>                                                          
  $('<%= j(render :partial => 'reply', :object => @reply) %>').appendTo($('#replies'));
<% else %>
  alert('@reply.errors.full_messages.join(',')');                                      
<% end %>
```

More refer to [Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)